# Get fragment content from baseactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app always use the same menu, so I had defines a BaseActivity, and each activity extends now BaseActivity.

The thing is one element of the menu is used to synchronize system. So depending of the activity I'm in, it should refresh different elements : listview, map, etc...

I'm able to know which activity is on top using SharedPreference on onStartMethod.

But from my BaseActivity, I'm unable to retrieves sub- Activities and fragments inside them.

I have :

```
public class FragmentTabsPdv extends BaseActivity
```

Inside FragmentTabsPdv, I have a Sherlock Tab, with 2 fragment :

```
ListPdvTabFragment extends SherlockFragment  
MapPdvTabFragment extends SherlockFragment
```

Inside ListPdvTabFragment, I want to refresh my ListView, but I don't know how to reach it from BaseActivity.

Of course, my menu is defines in BaseActivity:

The synchronize menu start a AsyncTask who get new content from server, and update sqlite db.
and the end of the process onPostExecute, I need to update my elements :

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (lTiendas == null){
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Hubo un error al sincronizar los datos, intentalo más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if (BaseActivity.refreshItem != null) {
        String frontActivity = prefs.getString("FrontActivity", "");
        if (!frontActivity.isEmpty()){
            if (frontActivity.equals("ListPdvTabFragment")){
                // get List to Refresh 
            }
        }


        BaseActivity.completeRefresh();
    } else {

        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DashBoard.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(i);

        if ((SplashScreen) ctx != null)
            ((SplashScreen) ctx).finish();
    }

}
```

Tab Activity :

```
public class FragmentTabsPdv extends BaseActivity {
private ArrayList<Pdv> listaPdv;
private Usuario mUser;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private Context ctx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    DatabaseHandlerTienda db = new DatabaseHandlerTienda(this);
    // listaPdv = (ArrayList<Pdv>) db.getAllTiendas();
    String jsonUser = prefs.getString("usuario", "");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    mUser = gson.fromJson(jsonUser, Usuario.class);
    listaPdv = db.getAllTiendas();

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Lista");
    tab1.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_view_as_list);

    ActionBar.Tab tab2 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    tab2.setText("Mapa");
    tab2.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_location_map);

    // create the two fragments we want to use for display content

    tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener<ListPdvTabFragment>(this, "lista", ListPdvTabFragment.class));
    tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener<MapPdvTabFragment>(this, "mapa", MapPdvTabFragment.class));

    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
}

public ArrayList<Pdv> getListaPdv() {
    return listaPdv;
}

public void setListaPdv(ArrayList<Pdv> listaPdv) {
    this.listaPdv = listaPdv;
}

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /**
     * Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * 
     * @param activity
     *            The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag
     *            The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz
     *            The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            // ft.attach(mFragment);
            ft.show(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            // ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.hide(mFragment); // Optimize map display
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    case R.id.menu_sync:
        DatabaseHandlerTienda db = new DatabaseHandlerTienda(this);
        ArrayList<Pdv> lTiendas = db.getAllTiendas();

        // adbTienda.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void refresh() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_action_view, null);

    Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.refresh);
    rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    iv.startAnimation(rotation);

    refreshItem.setActionView(iv);
    // Sincronize:

    SyncData sd = new SyncData(ctx);
    sd.execute();
    // GET LISTVIEW FRAGMENT AND UPDATE VIEW
}

}
```

Comment: could you not just create a getter?

Comment: Could you explain a litle bit your idea? I can get listView if I can get the instance of the fragment

Comment: I'm not sure I know exactly what you want but, create an instance of your fragment and create a getter method to return the variables?

Comment: Why are you using shared prefs to save the current activity? If they all extend BaseActivity you can override onOptionsItemSelected and you can also do the same within fragments.

Comment: I dont want to create a new instance, I need to get the existing instance of my fragment. But I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menu item should eventually call an abstract method, the signature of with is in `BaseActivity` and the implementation of which is defined in each child `Activity` to your `BaseActivity` (e.g. `FragmentTabsPdv`). For example:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity {
    protected abstract void refresh();
}
```

And your child `Activity`:

```
public class FragmentTabsPdv extends BaseActivity {
    protected void refresh(){
        // This should update your Fragment
    }
}
```

Looks like you'll want to call the `refresh()` method in `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`. Since you have references to the Fragment's in your child Activities, you should be able to refresh appropriately from there.

If you need to get a reference to the `Fragment` that is displayed, you should be able to do so using the `Activity`'s `FragmentManager`. Your layout xml should have something like a `FrameLayout` to hold your `Fragments`, right? Possibly with the id `android.R.id.content`? Use your `FragmentTabsPdv`'s `FragmentManager` (you can get it using `getFragmentManager()` or `getSupportFragmentManager()`) to get the `Fragment` held in that content container. Then you can call the appropriate method.

Comment: a problem is getting the fragment reference in FragmentTabsPdv

Comment: Aw, I see. So your layout xml should have something like a FrameLayout to hold your Fragments, right? Possibly with the id android.R.id.content? Use your FragmentTabsPdv FragmentManager (e.g. getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManager()) to get the Fragment held in that content container.

Comment: I override onOptionsItemSelected in my activity, implement abstract method refresh(), and I could get my fragment easily! Tx

Comment: Great, Juliatzin! Glad I could help